# What are Brinkmann coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, gravitational-waves

I am studying gravitational waves and I find it hard to understand Brinkmann coordinates.

All I can say is that they are such, that the GW metric takes a certain form in $(u,v,x,y)$: $$\mathrm{d}s^2 = H(u,x,y)\mathrm{d}u^2 + 2\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v + \mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2.$$
How do they relate to cartesian coordinates? Or are they something different?

What does it mean that $\partial_v$ is a null vector field? I know what is a null vector but how do I tell if $\partial_\mu$ is null or time(space)like?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please only ask *one question per post* — only ask several if they are so closely related that it wouldn't make sense to split them up since they cannot reasonably be answered separately. That way, users that might be able to answer one question but not the others still can provide useful, complete answers to a question. It would be interesting if you would make one question for understanding Brinkmann coordinates, and another one for the null vector field (which does not depend on the specific Brinkmann coordinates, even though they provide an example)

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates $u$ and $v$ are retarded/advanced time coordinates.  I guess with your signs, it would make most sense to define
$$
u \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( z - t \right),
\qquad
v \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( z + t \right).
$$
Just plug those into the metric you wrote, with $H=0$, and you should get Minkowski.  So this is just a coordinate transformation.

Physically, this means that fields that move at the speed of light in the $\pm z$ direction must be functions of $u$ **or** $v$, but not both.  (Though fields that move at the speed of light in directions other than $\pm z$ would be functions of both.)

[You can tell if a vector is null, spacelike, or timelike just by contracting the vector with itself and the metric and looking at the sign of the result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Causal_structure).  If the result is exactly 0, you have a null vector.